# Fusion Tables URL is too long

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a chart in Fusion Tables and I want to embed it into a HTML page. But the link Fusion Tables generated was too long and caused a 414 error:

> https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?containerId=googft-gviz-canvas&q=select+col0%2C+col2+from+1bYyqOSoa5ydbAIktz4FA_0p_irtl8Ejkrs3PPZg+order+by+col0+asc&viz=GVIZ&t=AREA&rmax=250&uiversion=2&gco_forceIFrame=true&gco_hasLabelsColumn=true&gco_vAxes=%5B%7B%22title%22%3A%22Difficulty%22%2C+%22minValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22maxValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22useFormatFromData%22%3Atrue%2C+%22viewWindow%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3Anull%2C+%22min%22%3Anull%7D%2C+%22logScale%22%3Afalse%2C+%22titleTextStyle%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23222%22%2C+%22fontSize%22%3A%2213%22%2C+%22italic%22%3Afalse%2C+%22bold%22%3Atrue%7D%2C+%22textStyle%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23222%22%2C+%22fontSize%22%3A12%2C+%22bold%22%3Afalse%2C+%22italic%22%3Afalse%7D%2C+%22gridlines%22%3A%7B%22count%22%3A%227%22%2C+%22color%22%3A%22%23cccccc%22%7D%2C+%22minorGridlines%22%3A%7B%22count%22%3A%220%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22useFormatFromData%22%3Atrue%2C+%22viewWindow%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3Anull%2C+%22min%22%3Anull%7D%2C+%22minValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22maxValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22logScale%22%3Afalse%7D%5D&gco_useFirstColumnAsDomain=true&gco_isStacked=false&gco_booleanRole=certainty&gco_hAxis=%7B%22useFormatFromData%22%3Afalse%2C+%22viewWindow%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3Anull%2C+%22min%22%3Anull%7D%2C+%22minValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22maxValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22title%22%3A%22Block%22%2C+%22titleTextStyle%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23222%22%2C+%22fontSize%22%3A%2213%22%2C+%22italic%22%3Afalse%2C+%22bold%22%3Atrue%7D%2C+%22gridlines%22%3A%7B%22count%22%3A%225%22%2C+%22color%22%3A%22%23cccccc%22%7D%2C+%22formatOptions%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%22inline%22%2C+%22scaleFactor%22%3Anull%7D%2C+%22logScale%22%3Afalse%2C+%22format%22%3A%220.%23%23%22%7D&gco_legend=none&gco_title=Dogechain+difficulty+over+79000+blocks&gco_titleTextStyle=%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23000000%22%2C+%22fontSize%22%3A%2224%22%2C+%22bold%22%3Atrue%7D&gco_fontName=Comic+Sans+MS&gco_domainAxis=%7B%22direction%22%3A1%7D&gco_backgroundColor=%7B%22fill%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%7D&gco_series=%7B%220%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%22%234a86e8%22%2C+%22lineWidth%22%3A2%7D%7D&width=500&height=300

Even if I convert `&amp;` to `&`, the error still existed. If I convert `%x` to the correct char, the chart wouldn't work as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Make it shorter.  A couple of options:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?containerId=googft-gviz-canvas&q=select+col0%2C+col2+from+1bYyqOSoa5ydbAIktz4FA_0p_irtl8Ejkrs3PPZg+order+by+col0+asc&viz=GVIZ&t=AREA&rmax=250&uiversion=2&gco_forceIFrame=true&gco_hasLabelsColumn=true&gco_vAxes=%5B%7B%22title%22%3A%22Difficulty%22%2C+%22minValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22maxValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22useFormatFromData%22%3Atrue%2C+%22viewWindow%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3Anull%2C+%22min%22%3Anull%7D%2C+%22logScale%22%3Afalse%2C+%22titleTextStyle%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23222%22%2C+%22fontSize%22%3A%2213%22%2C+%22italic%22%3Afalse%2C+%22bold%22%3Atrue%7D%2C+%22textStyle%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23222%22%2C+%22fontSize%22%3A12%2C+%22bold%22%3Afalse%2C+%22italic%22%3Afalse%7D%2C+%22gridlines%22%3A%7B%22count%22%3A%227%22%2C+%22color%22%3A%22%23cccccc%22%7D%2C+%22minorGridlines%22%3A%7B%22count%22%3A%220%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22useFormatFromData%22%3Atrue%2C+%22viewWindow%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3Anull%2C+%22min%22%3Anull%7D%2C+%22minValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22maxValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22logScale%22%3Afalse%7D%5D&gco_useFirstColumnAsDomain=true&gco_isStacked=false&gco_booleanRole=certainty&gco_hAxis=%7B%22useFormatFromData%22%3Afalse%2C+%22viewWindow%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3Anull%2C+%22min%22%3Anull%7D%2C+%22minValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22maxValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22title%22%3A%22Block%22%2C+%22titleTextStyle%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23222%22%2C+%22fontSize%22%3A%2213%22%2C+%22italic%22%3Afalse%2C+%22bold%22%3Atrue%7D%2C+%22gridlines%22%3A%7B%22count%22%3A%225%22%2C+%22color%22%3A%22%23cccccc%22%7D%2C+%22formatOptions%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%22inline%22%2C+%22scaleFactor%22%3Anull%7D%2C+%22logScale%22%3Afalse%2C+%22format%22%3A%220.%23%23%22%7D&gco_legend=none&gco_title=Dogechain+difficulty+over+79000+blocks&gco_titleTextStyle=%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23000000%22%2C+%22fontSize%22%3A%2224%22%2C+%22bold%22%3Atrue%7D&gco_fontName=Comic+Sans+MS&gco_domainAxis=%7B%22direction%22%3A1%7D&gco_backgroundColor=%7B%22fill%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%7D&gco_series=%7B%220%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%22%234a86e8%22%2C&width=500&height=300

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?containerId=googft-gviz-canvas&q=select+col0%2C+col2+from+1bYyqOSoa5ydbAIktz4FA_0p_irtl8Ejkrs3PPZg+order+by+col0+asc&viz=GVIZ&t=AREA&rmax=250&uiversion=2&gco_forceIFrame=true&gco_hasLabelsColumn=true&gco_vAxes=%5B%7B%22title%22%3A%22Difficulty%22%2C+%22minValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22maxValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22useFormatFromData%22%3Atrue%2C+%22viewWindow%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3Anull%2C+%22min%22%3Anull%7D%2C+%22logScale%22%3Afalse%2C+%22titleTextStyle%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23222%22%2C+%22fontSize%22%3A%2213%22%2C+%22italic%22%3Afalse%2C+%22bold%22%3Atrue%7D%2C+%22textStyle%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23222%22%2C+%22fontSize%22%3A12%2C+%22bold%22%3Afalse%2C+%22italic%22%3Afalse%7D%2C+%22gridlines%22%3A%7B%22count%22%3A%227%22%2C+%22color%22%3A%22%23cccccc%22%7D%2C+%22minorGridlines%22%3A%7B%22count%22%3A%220%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22useFormatFromData%22%3Atrue%2C+%22viewWindow%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3Anull%2C+%22min%22%3Anull%7D%2C+%22minValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22maxValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22logScale%22%3Afalse%7D%5D&gco_useFirstColumnAsDomain=true&gco_isStacked=false&gco_booleanRole=certainty&gco_hAxis=%7B%22useFormatFromData%22%3Afalse%2C+%22viewWindow%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3Anull%2C+%22min%22%3Anull%7D%2C+%22minValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22maxValue%22%3Anull%2C+%22title%22%3A%22Block%22%2C+%22titleTextStyle%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23222%22%2C+%22fontSize%22%3A%2213%22%2C+%22italic%22%3Afalse%2C+%22bold%22%3Atrue%7D%2C+%22gridlines%22%3A%7B%22count%22%3A%225%22%2C+%22color%22%3A%22%23cccccc%22%7D%2C+%22formatOptions%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%22inline%22%2C+%22scaleFactor%22%3Anull%7D%2C+%22logScale%22%3Afalse%2C+%22format%22%3A%220.%23%23%22%7D&gco_title=Dogechain+difficulty+over+79000+blocks&gco_titleTextStyle=%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23000000%22%2C+%22fontSize%22%3A%2224%22%2C+%22bold%22%3Atrue%7D&gco_fontName=Comic+Sans+MS&gco_domainAxis=%7B%22direction%22%3A1%7D&gco_backgroundColor=%7B%22fill%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%7D&gco_series=%7B%220%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%22%234a86e8%22%2C+%22lineWidth%22%3A2%7D%7D&width=500&height=300

Comment: Thanks, but **how** to do that?

Comment: I just removed a few characters (one of the query parameters in each case) that didn't seem like they would matter much. The second one, I see the difference (the legend on the right hand side).